# Pounds symbol problem

Tags: fonts, symbols

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[5]
    \pounds2600
    \begin{solution}
        \pounds 6
    \end{solution}

\question[5]
    \pounds2600
    \begin{solution}
        \[
            \begin{cases}
                C = \pounds 4 \\
                B = \pounds 7
            \end{cases}
        \]
    \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` solution, but it does not work for the second question.

How to make sure it's "ALWAYS" the `\pounds` symbol?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `\text{\pounds}` or `\textit{\pounds}` in math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\pounds` symbol is often difficult to manage; in this case you can get around the issue by redefining `\mathsterling` to use `\textsterling`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font

\renewcommand{\mathsterling}{\textrm{\textsterling}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[5]
    \pounds2600
    \begin{solution}
        \pounds 6
    \end{solution}

\question[5]
    \pounds2600
    \begin{solution}
        \[
            \begin{cases}
                C = \pounds 4 \\
                B = \pounds 7
            \end{cases}
        \]
    \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be a good idea to add that into the `iwona` package?

Comment: the ctan records indicate that `iwona` *is* maintained, and a request for update has been sent to the appropriate maintainers.